# Fabric | Android App | High no. of crashed/10k sessions but crash details not vsisible

Tags: android, crashlytics, fabric.io

we are using Fabric for crash analysis of our android app, since yesterday it is showing a high number of crashes/10k sessions, whereas the exact crash detail(s) is not visible anywhere, anyone faced this? what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric has some edge cases where their calculation goes bad.

Check in the `Launch status for <your version>` the number of sessions (at the bottom), if it's below 10k, don't trust the `crashes/10k sessions` number.
I sometimes get one crash, but on a version that's only rolled out to 1%, and has <1k sessions, and their `crashes/10k` number can reach absurd figures.

Another edge case where their calculation breaks, is when you have 0 crashes, then also, the `crashes/10k` number is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks but my sessions are in the range of 100k's and crash count is also not zero. Also, can't see the same in play store console and neither getting a reply from fabric team.

Comment: are you seeing this number in the `Launch status for XXX` screen? if you are, there's a link `All issues for XXX` you can press to see that version's crashes.

Comment: Yes, am seeing this number on the Launch status screen but number seems Ok on the All issues screen. Could this be resolved by uploading mapping.txt file manually, if yes, how to upload it manually for an android app?

Comment: `but number seems Ok on the All issues screen` there's no such number in the `All Issues` screen, you mean you divide then number of crashes in the `All Issues` screen by the number of sessions from the `Launch status` screen, and it doesn't match? are those numbers in the same ball park? can you give exact numbers?

Comment: Sharing approx numbers -total count of crashes on all issues screen - 400, crashes per 10k session on launch status screen - 1500, total no. of sessions approx 200000 ( 0.2 million)

Comment: also the total number of crashes on the launch status screen are approx 7k, with investigation recommended against it

Comment: is it possible you have set a small time frame on the `all issues` screen, which makes the 400 number lower then it should be? set it to `last 90 days` and see if it increases. I think the `crashes/10k` comes from dividing the two numbers on the `launch status` screen only (#crashes, #sessions), and it might be stats for a single date only (it says `TOP ISSUES FOR <version>, WED AUG 16TH`